# NameError in a Discord bot program

Tags: python, nameerror, discord.py

I started writing my first Discord bot, but I ran into a little problem. Why is my code not working ?

```
@bot.command()
async def msg(user : str, text : str):
    s = message.server
    await bot.send_message(s.get_member_named(name = user), text)
```

On the idea this command writes to users of the server on behalf of the bot

Error:

```
================== RESTART: C:/Users/Roman-PC/Desktop/t2.py ==================
Logged in as
FiveStar Role Play
470014458215792641
------
Ignoring exception in command msg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Roman-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 50, in wrapped
    ret = yield from coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/Roman-PC/Desktop/t2.py", line 47, in msg
    s = message.server
NameError: name 'message' is not defined

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Roman-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 846, in process_commands
    yield from command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Roman-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 374, in invoke
    yield from injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Roman-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 54, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'message' is not defined
```

I am quite a beginner in python programming

---

I tried to create a new bot, but got a new error

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random

FiveStarBot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
client = discord.Client()

@FiveStarBot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Connection success!')
    print('Name: ',FiveStarBot.user.name)
    print('ID: ',FiveStarBot.user.id)

@FiveStarBot.command()
async def message(name : str, text : str):
    s = message.server
    await FiveStarBot.send_message(s.get_member_named(name = name), text)
```

Its full code of bot w/o token.

```
================= RESTART: C:/Users/Roman-PC/Desktop/ggg.py =================
Connection success!
Name:  FiveStar Role Play
ID:  470014458215792641
Ignoring exception in command message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Roman-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 50, in wrapped
    ret = yield from coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/Roman-PC/Desktop/ggg.py", line 16, in message
    s = message.server
AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute 'server'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Roman-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 846, in process_commands
    yield from command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Roman-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 374, in invoke
    yield from injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Roman-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 54, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute 'server'
```

Comment: `NameError`s can occur when the name you are trying to use is not in the current scope. [9.1 A Word About Names and Objects, and 9.2 Python Scopes and Namespaces from the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-word-about-names-and-objects)  - are good reads.  I'm not familiar enough with asyncio to know how this can happen when a coroutine is executing.

Comment: Where does `message` come from in `s = message.server`?  Have you imported it, is it global?

Answer (score 0):

The `message` in `message.server` is the `message` command, which doesn't have a `server`.  (That's what the error is telling you)  You should pass the [invocation context](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#invocation-context) into the command with `pass_context=True`

```
@FiveStarBot.command(pass_context=True)
async def message(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, text : str):
    await FiveStarBot.send_message(member, text)
```

This takes advantage of a [`discord.py` converter](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#converter) to do the name lookup for you