# Issue sending file via Discord bot (Python)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
if message.content.upper().startswith("!HEADPATS"):
    time.sleep(1)
    with open('tenor.gif', 'rb') as picture:
      await client.send_file(channel, picture)
```

I've got my discord bot up and running (everything's written in python). I'm trying to get the bot to send a .gif in the channel upon the command "!headpats". The file is uploaded and the code compiles fine, but when the !headpats command is called via discord, the compiler spits this out...

```
File "main.py", line 106, in on_message
    await client.send_file(channel, picture)
NameError: name 'channel' is not defined
```

Comment: You need to resolve the channel through the message: `message.channel`.  There's a duplicate around here somewhere.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh https://stackoverflow.com/a/51468829/3271649
This is it I think...

Comment: @PatrickHaugh That patched everything up. Thanks for the help!

Comment: [This is the closest I could find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51499616/how-to-find-channel-name-in-discord-py-async/51499787#51499787) which actually isn't a very good duplicate.  I'll write up a proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you get inside your `on_message` event is the [`Message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message) that was received.  If you want to infer the `channel` it's in, the `server` it's on, the `author` who wrote it, etc., you'll have to resolve those attributes through the `message`. (`message.channel`, `message.server`, and so on).

If you're using the `discord.ext.commands` extension, then you first need to resolve the message as an attribute of the [invocation context](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#invocation-context): `ctx.message.channel`, for example.