# Get message object from commands in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm searching the way to get the message object using the discord commands. Here is what I mean:

```
BotClient = discord.Client()
@BotClient.event
async def on_message(msg):
      print(type(msg)) # prints out <class 'discord.message.Message'>. As far as I know, that means that msg is an instance of this discord.message.Message class
      for I in msg.server.members: # I can call a members atribute
          print(I.nick) # prints out the nicknames of all present users
BotClient.run(token)
```

But here is the example of code with commands:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
BotClient = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ".") 
@BotClient.command()
async def read(*args):
      print(type(args)) # That is a tuple, that contains only the content of the message
      for I in args:
          print(type(I)) # That is a string
BotClient.run(token)
```

My question is, can I somehow get the same message object using the discord.py commands module without writing the commands manually using `on_message()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52393542/issue-sending-file-via-discord-bot-python/52393723#52393723

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @PatrickHaugh , I've finally figured out how to do this. Here is the code that does exactly the same thing as my first code upper:

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
      print("Ready!")
@bot.command(pass_context=True) # You need to allow to pass the Context object to the command function
async def test(cntx, *args): 
          for I in cntx.message.server.members: #Calling the list of members of current server, where the message was sent
              print(I.nick) # Printing out all nicknames
bot.run(token)
```